# Getting Error while reading HDF5 file of pointcloud data

Tags: python, hdf5, point-cloud-library

I get this error whenever I try to read hdf5 file:

> OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name =
>   '/content/sample_data/data/hdf5_data/data_training.h5', errno = 2,
>   error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)**

Code:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('/content/sample_data/data/hdf5_data/data_training.h5', 'r') as f:
   print(f)
```

Solution:

## installed the packages

```
!sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
!pip install h5py
import h5py
f = h5py.File('/content/data/hdf5_data/data_testing.h5', 'r')
f
```

output:

Comment: Can you post the code you used that created the error as per a reproducible example?

Comment: import h5py
with h5py.File('/content/sample_data/data/hdf5_data/data_training.h5', 'r') as f:
   print(f)

Comment: I assume the file exists at that location. Have you verified `ata_testing.h5` is a valid HDF5 file? You can test with other utilities. I suggest: `h5dump` or `HDFView` (both from HDF5 Group).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion....data_testing.hdf5 file is a valid hdf5 file. It contains point cloud data along with label. Now I am able to view the data and label of HDF5 file.

Comment: The paths in you two bits of code are different. So I guess there might be an issue with the filepath